# wp_redirect() not working - URL remains the same

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm generating query parameters randomly and then redirecting to the same URL with those query parameters assigned.

To do this, I'm using `wp_redirect()`, however, my URL stays the same and no parameters are appended.

My approach follows similar to the [accepted answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109094/wp-redirect-and-sending-variables).

My approach:

```html
<?php

/*
* Create a secure, random string
*/

function random_str(
  int $length = 12,
  string $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
): string {
  if ($length < 1) {
    throw new \RangeException("Length must be a positive integer");
  }
  $pieces = [];
  $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
      $pieces []= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
  }
  return implode('', $pieces);
}

// echo random_str();

/*
* Redirect user to homepage with query string attached
*/


// echo home_url();

$redirect_url = home_url() ."?ref=". random_str();
echo $redirect_url;

function redirect_pages() {

  if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) )   {
    wp_redirect( "location:". $redirect_url );
    exit;
  }

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_pages' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code:

1. PHP is not like JS, you've defined `$redirect_url` outside the function and expecting it to be available inside the function which will not happen in php.
2. `"location:"` this location thing is not required in the WordPress function for redirect, only a url is required without `location:`
3. `is_page( 'homepage' )` you're checking if the current page is a page with the slug `homepage`, if you're looking for the actual homepage then you should use `is_front_page()`

here is the simplified code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Create a secure, random string
 */
function vh_wp_random_str( $length = 12 ) {
    $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    if ( $length < 1 ) {
        throw new \RangeException( 'Length must be a positive integer' );
    }

    $pieces = array();
    $max    = mb_strlen( $keyspace, '8bit' ) - 1;

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i ) {
        $pieces [] = $keyspace[ random_int( 0, $max ) ];
    }

    return implode( '', $pieces );
}

function vh_wp_redirect_pages() {
    if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) ) {
        $redirect_url = add_query_arg( array( 'ref' => vh_wp_random_str() ), home_url() );
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'vh_wp_redirect_pages' );
```

**Note:** I am using `wp_safe_redirect` because you're redirecting to a local address, if you have to redirect to external websites then `wp_redirect` should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers, 3 very valid points. Upon implementing your approach however, I get stuck in a redirect loop. Looking to only redirect the once. I guess this is because the `if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) )` is always valid, as we're redirecting back to the homepage?

Comment: Yes, that could be also possible.